# Grails spring security: auth failure redirect

Tags: grails, spring-security

I'm using grails 3 with spring security, and when I try to access a resource with ajax and it fails, it redirects to the login page.
However it seems to me that it would be easier for my xhr to just catch a 40x (401 or 403 for example) response and then redirect to the login page by itself, as a 302 from a xhr does not change the url.

So how can I make it so that spring security sends a 40x for unauthorized access instead of a 302 to /login ?

Thanks

Comment: Thanks @Joshua Moore for finding the duplicate. However the answer seems to have a lot of boilerplate code. Is there no easier solution to this?

Comment: It may seem that way, but if you dig into the Spring Security documentation (not just the grails plugin portion) you'll see this is the recommended approach. Honestly once you have it in place it's unobtrusive.